# React horizontal scrollbar

Tags: reactjs

Really new to React, so forgive me if this is on page 1 of the book...

I've got a small drag and drop sample working in React. I can drag a `<div>` from the bottom of my page into a "target" `<div>` up the top. The drop handler modifies the state and the dropped element appears in the target.

All dropped elements appear in the target one after another, horizontally.

And there is the problem: I want the target div to scroll all the way to the right to show me the one I just dropped.

I added some code to my drop handler that found the target (via refs) and set `scrollLeft` to a big number. **It causes a scroll, but never to the end**. I'm assuming that is because I'm setting `scrollLeft` on the element before it has been rendered with the new state, and so it is set to the "previous maximum".

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: When are you calling scrollLeft? If you're using setState it takes an optional callback that runs after render has completed.

Comment: @LodeRunner28 Brilliant - if you make an answer about the optional 2nd arg to `setState` I'll accept it - fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.setState` accepts a second optional parameter which is callback that runs after the render has completed.

For example,

```
this.setState({ /* your state */ }, function() { 
    ... 
    this.refs.yourRef.scrollLeft = /* someValue */;
});
```

Comment: For this to work, i have assign value to scrollLeft, like as follows-

`this.refs.yourRef.scrollLeft= <someValue > `

Comment: Why is this accepted answer when scrollLeft is not a function but a property?